# How to use function to define a string in C

Tags: c, string, function, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Define_string(char *str)
{
    str = "hello";
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char my_string[100] = {'\0'}

    Define_string(my_string);
    printf("%s", my_string);

    return(0);
}
```

I am trying to use a function to define a string, but i just keep getting null or pointer conversion errors. How would you use a function to define a string declared in the main? im not trying to input the strings value but just define it with hard code.
To try to have a nested if-else that returns different strings.

Comment: You should use `strcpy` or similar, to actually write the string to the underlying memory for it to be available.

Comment: The problem is that you modify the *local* variable `str` to point somewhere else. A modification which is lost when the life-time of the variable ends as the function returns.

Comment: Unlike in other languages there is no real string type in C. I suggest you read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book, the subject is pretty vast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Define_string(char *str)
{
    strcpy(str, "hello");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char my_string[100] = {'\0'};

    Define_string(my_string);
    printf("%s", my_string);

    return(0);
}
```

if you use strcpy, it works.

Answer (score -1):

if you just define string hard code. use macro.

`#define Define_string(var,val) const char *var=val`

`Define_string(my_string,"hello");`